# Issue with display formatting multiple forms in one template in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to display three forms in one template. I have the forms displayed, but the forms are listed in a row one after another. I'm trying to get them to display in three separate columns.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>h1</th>
                <th>h2</th>
                <th>h3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form1.as_table }}</td>
                <td>{{ form2.as_table }}</td>
                <td>{{ form3.as_table }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When this renders, it gets displayed like this:

```
h1     h2     h3
form1
form2
form3
```

I want something like this:

```
h1     h2     h3
form1  form2  form3
```

How would I do that?

Page source:

[image]

Comment: What does the page source look like after its rendered? Do you need the `.as_table`s?

Comment: @jozzas I added the page source

Comment: Take a look at twitter bootstrap and it's grid layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this is what I had to do:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table>
            <th>h1</th>
            <td>{{ form1.as_table }}</td>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td>
        <table>
            <th>h2</th>
            <td>{{ form2.as_table }}</td>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td>
        <table>
            <th>h3</th>
            <td>{{ form3.as_table }}</td>
        </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```